# How to get the path for created pdf report and share it?

Tags: android, printing, pdf-generation, android-studio-3.0

I use this [***document***](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Custom_Document_Printing_Tutorial) to create a Pdf file. By hitting a button to create a pdf file, Pdf-Viewer opens the created pdf automatically. I would like to know where that temporary file is saved in the device to get its path and share with socials using ACTION_SEND Intent.

How can I get the created pdf file from below code?

```
@Override
public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes,
          PrintAttributes newAttributes,
          CancellationSignal cancellationSignal,
          LayoutResultCallback callback,
          Bundle metadata) {

myPdfDocument = new PrintedPdfDocument(context, newAttributes);

pageHeight = 
            newAttributes.getMediaSize().getHeightMils()/1000 * 72;
pageWidth = 
            newAttributes.getMediaSize().getWidthMils()/1000 * 72;

if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled() ) {
    callback.onLayoutCancelled();
    return;
}

if (totalpages > 0) {
   PrintDocumentInfo.Builder builder = new PrintDocumentInfo
      .Builder("print_output.pdf") // where is the path for this file
      .setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT)
      .setPageCount(totalpages);

   PrintDocumentInfo info = builder.build();
   callback.onLayoutFinished(info, true);
} else {
   callback.onLayoutFailed("Page count is zero.");
}
}
```

Comment: Well somewhere on your device. Take a file explorer app onyour device. Browse around and you will find it soon.

Comment: just my opinion: pdf generated in server, apps can download it, if u want to share, give link should more efficient

Comment: I don't want the pdf reader opens the created file, How to just save it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this library but I was used iText Library for create pdf in Android application.
This library provide all mathod for pdf create or add different things in pdf file.
[this is link for iText library for android](https://itextpdf.com/itext-android-demos)

in this library we need to enter output file path. so easily we get the path of created pdf file path.

Comment: Good to know. But why posting this as an answer? Its not an answer isnt it?

Comment: yup add in comment it's enough

Answer (score 0):

The pdf is saved in the system's PrintSpooler (app)'s storage so it is not externally accessible (you can see the path on the device logs during a print). It is also copied to the underlying Print Service's storage (if the user ends up using an installed Print Service) using the [getDocument](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/printservice/PrintJob.html#getDocument()) method.